# How to set gravity in styles in android?

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I have a textview in a horizontal linear layout, and the textview is being top aligned. I want it to be vertically aligned.

I have the textview set to a style called "arrow"

```
<style name="arrow">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item> 
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item> 
</style>
```

java

```
            LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(this);
            LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            LL.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams courseMargin = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            courseMargin.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
            LL.setLayoutParams(courseMargin);

                            // here I add more things into LL...

            TextView arrow = new TextView(this);
            arrow.setText(">");
            arrow.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.arrow);
            LL.addView(arrow);
```

However this is still not making it vertically aligned...

Does anyone know whats going here?

Thanks

Comment: post the code in your layout xml file that contains the textview

Comment: I create it using java code. I posted it above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javadocs for `setTextAppearance()` state:

> Sets the text color, size, style, hint color, and highlight color from
>   the specified TextAppearance resource.

Which doesn't include anything about position or gravity. I would guess that is why your gravity is not having any effect.

Try like this:

```
//for android:gravity
arrow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

//for android:layout_gravity
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
arrow.setLayoutParams(params);
```

That being said, since your `TextView` is width and height `WRAP_CONTENT`, `android:gravity` is not going to have any effect. So really the `android:layout_gravity` chunk of code should be all that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using `SetGravity` on your textView. [setGravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity%28int%29)